# Markdown editor to preserve URL links in text copied from browser

Tags: html, text-editor, markdown, wysiwyg

I am looking for a good Markdown editor to keep track of what I am reading and learning online to improve my web developer skills and stay in touch with latest technologies.

As I read sometimes huge amounts of information daily, I would like to keep track of just important bits and pieces from what I'm reading, not just bookmarks, lists of links or full articles. I would like to be as efficient as possible, and be able to use advantages of a Markdown editor, like this one on Stack Overflow website, but be able to paste text copied from web browser including the links too like in a WYSIWYG editor.

I have to mention that I use tools like Evernote, TagSpaces and mindmapping tools intensely like Freemind/Freeplane, but they lack what I really need to accomplish this.

As a web developer/programmer, I need tools to facilitate my own development too learning and keeping track of what I'm learning, not just tools to write code. Sometimes when you start learning like a new programming language, you glue information and code together and you may end-up with a small script/software, that you find after a while, you might not be able to redo-it from scratch as easily because you don't have a strong foundation. But easy accessible **short** and **relevant** information, **well structured** would allow you to do that, and I don't mean plain text when I'm referring to this.

Is there any Windows/Linux Markdown editor / WYSIWYG editor that allows these two things:

- easy internal linking between articles/files, maybe having suggestion list with internal links to already existing content that
  contain the inserted text that you want to transform into a link,
  same as on Wikipedia visual editor
- pasting rich text copied from browser in such a way that preserves the
  links, maybe also converting it to markdown code style?

Or any good idea/solution? Like using 2 good tools together? Or a rich text converter to Markdown text?

Answer (score 2):

You wanna go look here: [Electron by Github third party markdown apps](https://electron.atom.io/apps/?q=markdown).

There are no less than 10 different apps that work with Markdown in various ways depending on what you want.

[image: Electron Registry]

I personally like [Typora](https://typora.io), but it doesn't do links quite like your looking for.

[image: Typora]

There is also [QownNotes](http://www.qownnotes.org) which I tried earlier.  I found that I just didn't like it as much as I thought I should have, but it does have an impressive feature set, and has recently been updated.  It doesn't need to be, but can be,synced with OwnCloud, and can do quite a bit; including supporting you  with hyperlinks, tags, and local linking.

[image: QOwnNotes]

I am also a developer, and QOwnNotes has the potential of being a large organized library of knowledge.  I would try looking at the Apps with Electron first though, as they definitely have apps that correspond to what you are looking for.

Also check out [Gist](https://gist.github.com) by GitHub for a quick and dependable snippet storage system.   There is at least one client among the Electron Apps, but there are quite a few others to be found.

PS:  I also found TagSpaces and Evernote to be lacking.   They are cumbersome and inconvenient (TagSpaces fills your filesystem with extra files as markers - that can't be the best way).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Is a good answer. But I really got lost now.
After trying almost 10 apps from there, I've ended up almost giving up. 
I just want something like this: http://upndown.netgusto.com/ into a contextual option of pasting html or as a button on a markdown editor, which of course should have the option to structure the notes into notebooks, tags and easy internal [[linking]] like on mediawiki (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Links)

Comment: You can do that with QOwnNotes

Comment: @MarcelCozma Did that suggestion help you ?

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife it's a very good answer with screen captures too, but not the answer for me. Every Editor in that list is lacking something which other has, so I keep on looking. For the moment, I've ended up  just using Dynalist.io for tasks management and I installed a Dokuwiki instance on my server.

Comment: @MarcelCozma I hear you. Thank you for getting back to me. I asked something similar in Software Recommendations and cited you. [Copy Paste Cite](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42183/copy-paste-cite-to-markdown)

Comment: @MarcelCozma - sorry nothing clicked.  I'm picky about the stuff I use too.  If it doesn't suit match everything I want, I skip it.